# Krita, undo shift+middle drag rotation?

Tags: krita

In Blender, shift+middle drag is for moving the view. In Krita, just middle drag is doing that thing and shift+middle drag does image rotation. The thing is, I am accustomed to Blender that I keep accidentally use shift+middle drag in Krita, resulting in unwanted rotation.

It seems that the undo button does not undo the rotation. I could do shift+middle drag again to get the image straight, but that would require a very precise control to set the rotation to 0. And the "Image->Rotate->Rotate Image->Angle Custom" adds that value to the current rotation, not setting the image rotation to that value (that is, if the current rotation is 5 degrees, applying Angle Custom 90 does not make the image rotation to 90, but to 95).

Is there any easy way to undo the shift+middle drag rotation or an easy way to set the image rotation to 0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try *View > Canvas > Reset Canvas Rotation*

Note: You could also set up a keyboard shortcut for that. There isn't one set up by default. Go to *Settings > Configure Krita*  Then, in Keyboard Shortcuts look under *Menu > View* you will find the shortcut settings for "Reset Canvas Rotation". Add a new custom keyboard shortcut for it.  Maybe something like <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd>.  It will show up in the shortcut list as Alt+)